# Functional Parser example in Haskell using GHCi

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner of learning Haskell. Here is the problem I've encountered when using GHCi.

```
p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p =  do x <- item
        item
        y <- item
        return (x,y)

item :: Parser Char
item =  P (\inp -> case inp of
                      []     -> []
                      (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)])
```

item is another parser where item :: Parser Char, simply item is to parse a string

When I load the file then execute

```
parse p "abcdef"
```

An execption is then shown:

```
*** Exception: You must implement (>>=)
```

Any idea for fixing such problem ?

---

Updated information:

The Parser is defined as follow:

```
newtype Parser a =  P (String -> [(a,String)])

instance Monad Parser where
   return      :: a -> Parser a
   return v    =  P (\inp -> [(v,inp)])

   (>>=)       :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
   p >>= f     = --...
```

Comment: How is `Parser` defined? Did you define it or do you expect it to be defined by another library, and if so, which library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `do` notation, your `Parser` must be an instance of `Monad`:

```
instance Monad Parser where
  return :: a -> Parser a
  return = -- ...
  (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
  p >>= f = -- ...
```

The compiler needs you to fill in definitions of `return` and `>>=`.

`do` notation is syntatic sugar that desugars to use of `>>=` (pronounced "bind"). For example, your code desugars to:

```
p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p =  item >>= \x ->
     item >>= \_ ->
     item >>= \y ->
     return (x,y)
```

Or, with more explicit parentheses:

```
p = item >>= (\x -> item >>= (\_ -> item >>= (\y -> return (x,y))))
```

`>>=` describes how to combine a `Parser a` along with a function `a -> Parser b` to create a new `Parser b`.

Using your definition of `Parser`, a working `Monad` instance is

```
instance Monad Parser where
  return a = P $ \s -> [(a,s)]
  p >>= f = P $ concatMap (\(a,s') -> runParser (f a) s') . runParser p
  -- which is equivalent to
  -- p >>= f = P $ \s -> [(b,s'') | (a,s') <- runParser p s, (b,s'') <- runParser (f a) s']
```

Consider what `>>=` does in terms of a `p :: Parser a` and a function `f :: a -> Parser b`.

- when unwrapped, `p` takes a `String`, and returns a list of `(a,String)` pairs

  ```
  runParser p :: String -> [(a,String)]
  ```
- for each `(a,String)` pair, we can run `f` on the `a` to get a new parser `q`:

  ```
  map go . runParser p :: String -> [(Parser b,String)]
    where go :: (a, String) -> (Parser b, String)
          go (a,s') = let q = f a in (q, s')
  ```
- if we unwrap `q`, we get a function that takes a `String` and returns a list of `(b, String)` pairs:

  ```
  map go . runParser p :: String -> [(String -> [(b,String)],String)]
    where go :: (a, String) -> (String -> [(b,String)],String)
          go (a,s') = let q = f a in (runParser q, s')
  ```
- we can run that function on the `String` that was paired with the `a` to get our list of `(b, String) pairs immediately:

  ```
  map go . runParser p :: String -> [[(b,String)]]
    where go :: (a, String) -> [(b,String)]
          go (a,s') = let q = f a in runParser q s'
  ```
- and if we flatten the list-of-lists that results we get an `String -> [(b,String)]`, which is just unwrapped `Parser b`

  ```
  concat . map go . runParser p :: String -> [(b,String)]
    where go :: (a, String) -> [(b,String)]
          go (a,s') = let q = f a in runParser q s'
  ```

Comment: Thanks, rampion. The information is updated and show the definition of Parser. So how can I implement >>= in the given example.

Comment: Tony Ngan: what I and user5402 were asking for was a definition of the `Parser` datatype, not the definition of `item`. I think I was able to infer it from your use of the `P` constructor, but tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've updated it again. `newtype Parser a =  P (String -> [(a,String)])` , so what does `s'` mean in `Monad` instance you have mentioned above.

Comment: tony.0919: I've fleshed out my description of how `>>=` is implemented. Let me know if you have any questions about it.